# Anyone know if opencl intellisense / color syntax exists for visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, opencl

Searching google i can find alot of information about cuda, but havent been able to find any information about OpenCL support in VS2012?

Also, adding color syntax to my .ocl files would be nice?

Comment: [Intel OpenCL SDK](http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk) comes with a Visual Studio addin which adds syntax coloring (and maybe intellisense?) for OpenCL files, but unfortunately there's no VS 2012 support yet, only 2008 and 2010.

Answer (score 3):

There's a work around to give this in Visual Studio 2008, it's a fairly lengthy explanation so I'll link the article here:

http://opencl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OpenCL%20Tutorials%20-%200

Some of the options might have moved, but I suspect you might get a VS2012 solution from these instructions.

Good luck!